# Best way to programatically assign class attributes from JSON

Tags: python, json, sqlite, sqlalchemy

The program I'm making needs to store users in a SQLite database using SQLAlchemy based on information received as JSON. My class definition for a User is:

```py
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = "users"

    address = Column(TEXT, primary_key=True)
    fullName = Column(TEXT)
    nickName = Column(TEXT)
    profilePictureId = Column(INTEGER)
    bio = Column(TEXT)
    online = Column(INTEGER)
    lastSeen = Column(TEXT)
    publicKey = Column(TEXT)
```

An example of the JSON I would receive would be:

```
{
    "address": "aayla",
    "publicKey": "key",
    "bio" = "test bio",
}
```

And here is how I am creating new `User` objects now:

```py
newUser = User(
    address = data["address"]
    publicKey = data["publicKey"]
    ...
)
```

What I would like to do is populate the attributes of my `User` class using values of the JSON keys of the same name automatically. Although what I am currently doing does work, I would rather use a more programmatic method if possible to make scope creep less painful in the event `User` attributes are added/changed. Does a more automatic way exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't really about JSON, at least not once you've decoded the JSON into a Python `dict`. Once you do that, you can simply pass the values as keyword arguments (since your parameter names match the original JSON keys):

```
newUser = User(**data)
```

However, this is a little fragile, unless you verify first that the key names are valid parameters. Better to encapsulate this in a class method.

```
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = "users"

    address = Column(TEXT, primary_key=True)
    fullName = Column(TEXT)
    nickName = Column(TEXT)
    profilePictureId = Column(INTEGER)
    bio = Column(TEXT)
    online = Column(INTEGER)
    lastSeen = Column(TEXT)
    publicKey = Column(TEXT)

    @classmethod
    def from_json(cls, data):
        # Validate data's keys here, and extract only
        # those values that User actually expects
        address = data['address']
        fullName = data['fullName']
        ...
        return User(address, fullName, ...)


newUser = User.from_json(data)
```